# Why does this bash command take up all space on device?

Tags: bash, unix, search

I'm a little new on searching via bash, so feel free to give me **suggestions on the methods to use** instead of this, which I'll never use again.

I'm searching for **occurances of a string, recursively in a directory**, with ~50 not-that-large php-files in it; some in current directory, some in directories beneath current dir, three levels of directories down at most.

The method I'm using is

```
find . | xargs grep "module" > module.txt
```

When in simple (one level) directories, this works fine, but in this case, the file became 4 GB large until it filled up *all space on the partition*. It wasn't even done yet.

Why is that file growing so large?

Comment: To understand recursion is to understand recursion

Comment: Why close? It's essentially a case of unintended recursion. As a concept, it certainly is programming-related.

Comment: Shell interaction seem to be a tricky issue for site selection. On one hand shells are programs you *use*, on the other hand they are Turing complete languages in which one writes *programs*. So site selection depends on a judgment call about whether you are "programming" or not. This is a one-liner which *I* would have introduced on Super User in the first place, but it is enough of a programmer's problem that I wouldn't vote to move it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`module.txt` is created before the pipeline starts, therefore it is included in the search. `grep` finds an instance of "module" in it, so a line is added to it containing the word "module". Which grep then finds, and adds. Which grep then finds, and adds. Which grep then finds, and adds. Which...

Comment: Nasty. Ok, that's the problem, could you point me to a solution? I.e. with another syntax or just something to add to this search?

Comment: @OP: Solution is to ensure your result file name does not contain the search keyword.

Comment: Store the file outside the search parameters.

Comment: @coddadict: of course, +1. Would this be faster or slower than what @MBO suggested?

Comment: @OP: I guess using recursive option with grep (as suggested by MBO) might be *faster* than this solution, since a single process will be involved and there will be no IPC. Others plz post your opinion.

Comment: Yes, using a recursive `grep` will be faster. But using `find` allows you to tune exactly which files you want to match.

Comment: One workaround: Tell find to exclude your results file, like so: find . -not -name results.txt -exec grep "modoule" {} + > results.txt

Answer (score 1):

And what is the output without `> module.txt`.

Why not try to use `grep -R "module" . > ../module.txt`?

Answer (score 1):

```
find /path -type f -iname "*.php" | while read -r FILE
do
  grep -H "module" "$FILE" >> "file_with_search_term_found.txt"
done
```

Or if your grep has recursive function,

```
grep -RH "module" *.php
```

Or with bash 4.0 shell

```
shopt -s globstar
for file in /path/**/*.php
do
   if [ -f "$file" ];then
      while read -r line 
      do
         case "$line" in
           *module* ) echo $line >> module.txt;;
         esac    
      done <"file"      
   fi

done
```

Comment: Or `find -name '*.php' -exec grep -q -H "module" {} \; -print > ../module.txt`.

Comment: i prefer `find /path -type f -iname "*.php" -exec grep -q -H "module" "{}" +; ...`